# Adding 30 minutes to time formatted as H:i in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

Having a nightmare at the moment and just can't see why it isn't working

I have a value in the form H:i (ie 10:00, 13:30) etc called $time

What I want to do is create two new values, $startTime which is 30 mins before $time and $endTime which is 30 mins after $time

I have tried the following but just doesn't seem to want to work

```
$startTime = date("H:i",strtotime('-30 minutes',$time));
$endTime = date("H:i",strtotime('+30 minutes',$time));
```

If I pass through 10:00 as $time and echo out both $startTime and $endTime I get:

```
$startTime = 00:30
$startTime = 01:30
```

Comment: How is the $time variable initialized?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but can you try `-30 minute` without the s?

Comment: @Pekka not an issue. It works fine, when not using $time. Must be a badly initialized value.

Comment: @Patonza I am getting it from a querystring, it has been passed from a form on the previous page.

@Pekka I had already tried that I am afraid, same result

Comment: @bateman can you show a timestamp value?

Comment: @Gordon you're right: if `+30 minutes` gives `01:30` then that is good old January 1, 1970 :)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime('10:00');
$startTime = date("H:i", strtotime('-30 minutes', $time));
$endTime = date("H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $time));
```

Comment: I am trying to do this 
$toTime = date("h:i", strtotime('+"'.$slot['duration'].'" minutes', $fromTime));

but it throws me the following error
A non well formed numeric value encountered

Answer (score 17):

In order for that to work `$time` has to be a timestamp. You cannot pass in "10:00" or something like `$time = date('H:i', '10:00');` which is what you seem to do, because then I get 0:30 and 1:30 as results too.

Try

```
$time = strtotime('10:00');
```

As an alternative, consider using DateTime (*the below requires PHP 5.3 though*):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', '10:00'); // create today 10 o'clock
$dt->sub(new DateInterval('PT30M'));              // substract 30 minutes
echo $dt->format('H:i');                          // echo modified time
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));               // add 1 hour
echo $dt->format('H:i');                          // echo modified time
```

or procedural if you don't like OOP

```
$dateTime = date_create_from_format('H:i', '10:00');
date_sub($dateTime, date_interval_create_from_date_string('30 minutes'));
echo date_format($dateTime, 'H:i');
date_add($dateTime, date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 hour'));
echo date_format($dateTime, 'H:i');
```

Answer (score 8):

I usually take a slightly different track to achieve this:

```
$startTime = date("H:i",time() - 1800);
$endTime = date("H:i",time() + 1800);
```

Where 1800 seconds = 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution does not work because `$time` is a string - it needs to be a Unix timestamp. You can do this instead:

```
$unix_time = strtotime('January 1 2010 '.$time); // create a unix timestamp
$startTime date( "H:i", strtotime('-30 minutes', $unix_time) );
$endTime date( "H:i", strtotime('+30 minutes', $unix_time) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$time = 30 * 60; //30 minutes
$start_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time() - $time);
$end_time = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time() + $time);
```

Comment: `Y-m-d H:i:s` not `h:i:s`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2016-10-10 15:00:00")+(60*30) );//2016-10-10 15:30:00
```

or

```
echo date( "H:i:s", strtotime("15:00:00")+(60*30) ); // 15:30:00
```

or

```
echo date( "H:i:s", strtotime(date("H:i:s"))+(60*30) ); // 15:30:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on previous answers, a function to do this could work like this (changing the time and interval formats however you like them according to [this for function.date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), and [this for DateInterval](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/php-dateinterval-class/)):

```
// Return adjusted start and end times as an array.

function expandTimeByMinutes( $time, $beforeMinutes, $afterMinutes ) {

    $time = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i', $time );
    $time->sub( new DateInterval( 'PT' . ( (integer) $beforeMinutes ) . 'M' ) );
    $startTime = $time->format( 'H:i' );
    $time->add( new DateInterval( 'PT' . ( (integer) $beforeMinutes + (integer) $afterMinutes ) . 'M' ) );
    $endTime = $time->format( 'H:i' );

    return [
        'startTime' => $startTime,
        'endTime'   => $endTime,
    ];
}

$adjustedStartEndTime = expandTimeByMinutes( '10:00', 30, 30 );

echo '<h1>Adjusted Start Time: ' . $adjustedStartEndTime['startTime'] . '</h1>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
echo '<h1>Adjusted End Time: '   . $adjustedStartEndTime['endTime']   . '</h1>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```