# Adding minutes to date time in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I'm really stuck with adding X minutes to a datetime, after doing lots of google'ing and PHP manual reading, I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

The date time format I have is:

`2011-11-17 05:05`: `year-month-day hour:minute`

Minutes to add will just be a number between 0 and 59

I would like the output to be the same as the input format with the minutes added.

Could someone give me a working code example, as my attempts don't seem to be getting me anywhere?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

```
$minutes_to_add = 5;

$time = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));

$stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

The [ISO 8601 standard for duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) is a string in the form of `P{y}Y{m1}M{d}DT{h}H{m2}M{s}S` where the `{*}` parts are replaced by a number value indicating how long the duration is.

For example, `P1Y2DT5S` means 1 year, 2 days, and 5 seconds.

In the example above, we are providing `PT5M` (or 5 minutes) to the `DateInterval` constructor.

Comment: With date: 2011-11-18 00:00 if I add 5 mins, I get 2012-04-18 00:00 as a result.

`
$time = new DateTime($_REQUEST['start']);
$time->add(new DateInterval('P' . $duration . 'M'));
$endTime = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
echo $endTime;
`

Applogies for the formatting, it appears I can't work this out either today ^_^

Comment: @LukeB:  Sorry, forgot a character.  Fixed my answer.

Comment: How is DateTime better than strtotime?

Comment: What does 'PT' represent?

Comment: @bozdoz It's not a question of which method is "better". `strtotime` produces a Unix timestamp as an `integer` which is helpful if you are for example sorting dates in php. The `DateTime` class provides options for object and procedural style operations. It's more readable and also has better support for handling differences between different timezones; for example, if you have a project that outputs dates for numerous different timezones sourced from the same data instance.

Comment: I ran into an issue with the timezone being off and had to do more reasearch. HEre is my solution based on the above correct answer:

    $minutes_to_add = 10;
    $time = new DateTime();
    $time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));
    $time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
    $timestamp = $time->format("Y/m/d G:i:s");

Comment: Any reason why `time() + $minutes_to_add * 60;` isn't viable?

Comment: @NicholasJohn16 https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php

>> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration period is represented by an integer value followed by a period designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of the specification is preceded by the letter T.

Comment: @Bad_Neighbor That formula only gives 5 minutes from now in seconds, which has four problems. What if we want 5 minutes from some other time than now? What if we want some other interval than 5 minutes? What happens when we represent dates in seconds on a 32-bit machine? What if we want to display the date in some other format than seconds? Using DateTime and DateInterval are a single way of doing everything time related that accounts for all these problems so you don't have to.

Comment: @TimCooper, you made my day. Was having lot of trouble reading dates from MongoDB which stores in UTC format. Your solution helped me and I could add my TZ offset to get correct date and time, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 151):

[PHP's DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) has a useful [modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) method which takes in easy-to-understand text.

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$dateTime->modify('+5 minutes');
```

You could also use string interpolation or concatenation to parameterize it:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$minutesToAdd = 5;
$dateTime->modify("+{$minutesToAdd} minutes");
```

Comment: Both of the top answers are great and work fine, but I prefer this one. Just seems simpler and more intuitive.

Comment: A benefit of this method is it can handle negative minutes (if you remove the +), unlike  the highest score answer.

Answer (score 55):

```
$newtimestamp = strtotime('2011-11-17 05:05 + 16 minute');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newtimestamp);
```

result is

> 2011-11-17 05:21:00

Live demo is [`here`](https://phpsandbox.io/n/lingering-mountain-mjek-pvln7)

If you are no familiar with [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) yet, you better head to [`php.net`](http://www.php.net/) to discover it's great power :-)

Comment: Most understanding one

Comment: Live demo is no longer available

Comment: @HasanAlyazidi thank you, I've updated the reference.

Comment: @Nemoden Nemoden Live demo link is broken, please remove it or update it. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this with native functions easily:

```
strtotime('+59 minutes', strtotime('2011-11-17 05:05'));
```

I'd recommend the DateTime class method though, just posted by Tim.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know why the approach set as solution didn't work for me.
So I'm posting here what worked for me in hope it can help anybody:

```
$startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//display the starting time
echo '> '.$startTime . "<br>";

//adding 2 minutes
$convertedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 minutes', strtotime($startTime)));

//display the converted time
echo '> '.$convertedTime;
```

Answer (score 8):

I thought this would help some when dealing with time zones too. My modified solution is based off of @Tim Cooper's solution, the correct answer above.

```
$minutes_to_add = 10;
$time = new DateTime();
**$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Toronto'));**
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));
$timestamp = $time->format("Y/m/d G:i:s");
```

The bold line, line 3, is the addition. I hope this helps some folks as well.

Answer (score 4):

A bit of a late answer, but the method I would use is:

```
// Create a new \DateTime instance
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-26 10:00:00');

// Modify the date
$date->modify('+5 minutes');

// Output
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or in PHP >= 5.4

```
echo (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2015-10-26 10:00:00'))->modify('+5 minutes')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give a variable that contains the minutes.

Then I think this is a great way to achieve this.

```
$minutes = 10;
$maxAge = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$maxAge->modify("+{$minutes} minutes");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtotime("+5 minute", $date);`

---

**Example:**

```
$date = "2017-06-16 08:40:00";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+5 minute", $date);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Brad and Nemoden in their answers above, strtotime() is a great function. Personally, I found the standard DateTime Object to be overly complicated for many use cases. I just wanted to add 5 minutes to the current time, for example.

I wrote a function that returns a date as a string with some optional parameters:

1.) time:String | ex: "+5 minutes" (default = current time)

2.) format:String | ex: "Y-m-d H:i:s" (default = "Y-m-d H:i:s O")

Obviously, this is not a fully featured method. Just a quick and simple function for modifying/formatting the current date.

```
function get_date($time=null, $format='Y-m-d H:i:s O')
{
    if(empty($time))return date($format);
    return date($format, strtotime($time));
}

// Example #1: Return current date in default format
$date = get_date(); 

// Example #2: Add 5 minutes to the current date
$date = get_date("+5 minutes"); 

// Example #3: Subtract 30 days from the current date & format as 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
$date = get_date("-30 days", "Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 1):

one line mysql datetime format

```
$mysql_date_time = (new DateTime())->modify('+15 minutes')->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

One more example of a function to do this: (changing the time and interval formats however you like them according to [this for function.date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), and [this for DateInterval](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/php-dateinterval-class/)):

(I've also written an [alternate form of the below function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767068/adding-30-minutes-to-time-formatted-as-hi-in-php/43215950#43215950).)

```
// Return adjusted time.

function addMinutesToTime( $dateTime, $plusMinutes ) {

    $dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Y-m-d H:i', $dateTime );
    $dateTime->add( new DateInterval( 'PT' . ( (integer) $plusMinutes ) . 'M' ) );
    $newTime = $dateTime->format( 'Y-m-d H:i' );

    return $newTime;
}

$adjustedTime = addMinutesToTime( '2011-11-17 05:05', 59 );

echo '<h1>Adjusted Time: ' . $adjustedTime . '</h1>' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Without using a variable:

```
 $yourDate->modify("15 minutes");
 echo $yourDate->format( "Y-m-d H:i");
```

With using a variable:

```
 $interval= 15;
 $yourDate->modify("+{$interval } minutes");  
 echo $yourDate->format( "Y-m-d H:i");
```

Comment: What is `$yourDate`? What does this answer add to the similar answers posted years before?

Comment: Dear @J.Money $yourDate means $variable name and Maybe my answer will be helpful for someone after 100 years. It does not matter when we should answer until question is not closed. I hope you will understand and remove negative marking.

Answer (score -1):

All that you need to do is:

1- put your time in the format you want

2- add minutes time in the string

3- use `strtotime()` function for converting string to time

Here is an example:

```
$limit = 10;
date("G:i", strtotime(date("h:i:sa") . ' + ' . $limit . ' minutes'))
```

First, we had our time `date("h:i:sa")` which we want to add minutes to it

Then, we concatinated a string of our value to be added to it which is "H-m-sa +10 minutes", just change th time and the value of `$limit`

After that, convert all of this to date type in `date()` function

**Note**, check first that `$limit` is an integer, sometimes you receive the value of `$limit` but not value.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Are you sure there is no answer suggesting the same? Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169206/285587)?

Comment: I faced the same problem and I answered my EXACT solution that I tried.