# PHP Add Time to Existing Stored Time

Tags: php

I am trying to add 55 minutes to a set time stored in the database. I am running an MySQL Query to get the time information. This is stored in the PHP Script as
      `$row['login_time']`.

If is getting stored in the database in the format like 2013-04-25 22:48:53 EDT.

I am trying to add 55 minutes to this time.

I have the following script but it is showing a value in 1969.

```
$seconds = 55 * 60;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['login_time'] + $seconds);
```

Comment: Poss. dup. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php

Comment: Use the DateTime class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: Your code doesn't work for the same reason that `'one' + 'five'` doesn't return `'six'`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario That's not a behaviour that would surprise me in PHP. I thought it would coerce the datetime string to the number 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert the `DATETIME` field to the value in seconds, you can use the php function [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$seconds = 55 * 60;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($row['login_time']) + $seconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the seconds after converting the date to a UNIX timestamp.

```
$seconds = 55 * 60;
$timestamp = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $row['login_time'])) + $seconds;
echo $timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to get PHP involved:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET timefield = timefield + INTERVAL 55 MINUTE
```

or

```
...
SET timefield = DATE_ADD(timefield, INTERVAL 55 MINUTE)
```