# Add minutes to datetime string

Tags: php, datetime

```
$datetime_from = '2013-08-27 14:17:00';
$datetime_till = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+45 minutes",$datetime_from));
```

The result is:

```
$datetime_till = '1970-01-01 01:00:00'
```

The expected result is

```
$datetime_till = '2013-08-27 15:02'
```

How to get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php

Comment: Is $datetime_from coming from a database?

Answer (score 1):

It will be like

```
$datetime_from = strtotime('2013-08-27 14:17:00');
$datetime_till = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+45 minutes",$datetime_from));
```

You need to convert `$datetime_from` to time

Orelse you can also try like(**Iam not sure**)

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i', $datetime_from);
$datetime_from = $dateTime->format('U');
$datetime_till = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+45 minutes",$datetime_from));
```

Comment: It provides the same answer: 1970-01-01 01:45:00

Comment: Probably the problem is that var_dump($datetime_from); outputs "'2013-08-27 17:00:00'"

Comment: If you are using `DateTime` classes, don't mix them with old `date()` or `strtotime()` functions.

Comment: What is the reason to down it..??

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
$datetime_till = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime("+45 minutes",strtotime($datetime_from)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead of old functional php.

```
$dateFrom = new \DateTime('2013-08-27 14:17:00');
$dateTill = new \DateTime('2013-08-27 14:17:00');
$dateTill->modify('+45 minutes');

// test if the dates are correct
echo $dateFrom->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). ' - '.$dateTill->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

There are numerous other methods you can benefit from the DateTime class.

Comment: This line fails: $datetime_till = new DateTime($datetime_from);

Comment: Probably the problem is that var_dump($datetime_from); outputs "'2013-08-27 17:00:00'". But how to fix it?

Comment: add a backslash before DateTime. $datetime_from must be a string with a valid format date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime object to do this in procedural style PHP like this:

```
$datetime_from = date_create('2013-08-27 14:17:00'); // Create a date object from the start date
$datetime_till = date_add($datetime_from, date_interval_create_from_date_string('45 minutes')); // Add the interval to the starting time
echo date_format($datetime_till, 'Y-m-d H:i'); // Format the date how you want it to be output
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use:

$datetime_from = strtotime('2013-08-27 14:17:00');

$datetime_till = date("Y-m-d H:i",$datetime_from+(45*60));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class for date/time modifications :

```
$datetime_from = new DateTime('2013-08-27 14:17:00');
$datetime_till = clone $datetime_from;
$datetime_till->modify('+45 minutes');

echo
    'From: ' . $datetime_from->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n".
    'Till: ' . $datetime_till->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Output will be :

```
From: 2013-08-27 14:17:00
Till: 2013-08-27 15:02:00
```

Valid [modify()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) formats are explained in [Date and Time Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

---

<sub>Please note that various [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) examples are not correct in date/time difference calculation. The simplest example is difference between `2013-03-31 21:00` and `2013-03-30 21:00`. Which for naked eye is exact 1 day difference, but if you do subtract this 2 dates, you will get `82800` seconds which is `0.95833333333333` days. This is because of the time change from winter to summer time. [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) handles leap years and time-zones properly.</sub>