# What's the best way of adding a time interval in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to add time to an existing date. I have 2 string variables:

```
$date     = "2013-01-05 10:55:15";
$interval =            "50:25:10";
```

I want to calculate the final date "2013-01-07 13:20:25". The hours in time can be bigger than 23, meaning that this interval can be greater than a whole day.

What's the best way to do this ?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [DateTime API](http://php.net/DateTime):

```
$date = new DateTime("2013-01-05 10:55:15");
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT50H25M10S"));
```

then you can convert it back to string with the same date format you would use with `date()` function, if you want to:

```
$string = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

For more information about the `DateInterval` definition, visit this page:

[DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php)

> The format starts with the letter P, for "period." Each duration
>   period is represented by an integer value followed by a period
>   designator. If the duration contains time elements, that portion of
>   the specification is preceded by the letter T.
>
> Here are some simple examples. Two days is P2D. Two seconds is PT2S.
>   Six years and five minutes is P6YT5M.

so in this case `PT50H25M10S` means 50 hours, 25 minutes, and 10 seconds

Note that DateInterval is available only since PHP 5.3, if you have to use lower version, you could use something like this:

```
 $time = strtotime("2013-01-05 10:55:15");
 $time += 55*60*60 + 25*60 + 10;
 $newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: *"The ISO 8601 standard for duration is a string in the form of `P{y}Y{m1}M{d}DT{h}H{m2}M{s}S` where the `{*}` parts are replaced by a number value indicating how long the duration is."* <- That's a snippet is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8169189/3965565). Combined with the above, these helped me finally understand DateInterval.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little tricky.

Normally what you would do here if it was a static period, or was a single period type, is something along the lines of:

```
$date = "2013-01-05 10:55:15";
$time = new DateTime($date);
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT5M'));
```

This would add 5 minutes to the datetime. However I doubt you can pass the whole interval in. So what you'll probably have to do is split the interval by : and then add each part of the interval (I assume it is dynamic?) to the date separately. So first hours, then minutes, then seconds

For more on this, see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 6):

You could first explode the interval and then get the hours, minutes, seconds, and then use DateTime's [`add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) to add the interval, like so:

```
$interval = '50:25:10';
$datestring = '2013-01-05 10:55:15';    
list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $interval); 

$date = new DateTime($datestring);    
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$hours.'H'.$minutes.'M'.$seconds.'S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[**Demo!**](https://3v4l.org/mH0S7)

Comment: @Vikas eval.in is down. Thanks for notifying. I've updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [DateTime->add()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php):

```
$date = new DateTime("2013-01-05 10:55:15");
$date->add(new DateInterval("PT50H25M10S"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs based on answers above, I made my function like this:

```
public function addTime($date, $time) {
    $atime = explode(":", $time);
    $_date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);
    $_date->add(new DateInterval("PT" . intval($atime[0])."H".intval($atime[1])."M".intval($atime[2])."S"));
    return $_date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
}
```

hope it helps someone