# Adding 5 minutes to a DateTime php variable?

Tags: php

I have this $date variable.

```
$date   = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s', $dates[1][0]);
```

My question is how to have a `$future` date in the same format as the `$date` but add 5 minutes to it?

Comment: Google or SO search or the related section would have answered this

Answer (score 0):

Refrence: [Adding minutes to date time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php)

```
$minutes_to_add = 5;

$time = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes_to_add . 'M'));

$stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Without **Variable**:

```
$time = new DateTime('2011-11-17 05:05');
$time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . '5' . 'M'));

$stamp = $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');

echo $stamp;
```

Comment: How is this written without the `$minutes_to_add` variable?

Answer (score 0):

That should works :

```
$format = 'D, d M Y H:i:s';
$future = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dates[1][0]);
$future->add(new DateInterval('P5M'));
echo $future->format($format) . "\n";
```