# DateTime current date + 2 mins compared to stored datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to compare these 2 DateTimes.
I'm storing one in a database that is stored whenever a new row is inserted.
The other one is the current DateTime, but I'm trying to add two minutes to it and then compare it.

My current code:

```
$time = $cached_data["last_update"];
$date = new DateTime ('now');
$datef = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// Check if the cached data has expired and if it has then update the data
if($datef > ($time)) {

    echo "updated";
}
```

Echoing both the $datef and the $time gives:

```
$datef: 2016-04-06 00:23:43

$time: 2016-04-05 18:21:03
```

and the script echoes out "updated".

I realize the time on my system and the time of my database are different, but how would I add the two minutes to the `$datef`and would this work?

Comment: `$date->add(new DateInterval('PT2M'));` - [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding minutes to date time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php)

Comment: Okay, so let's say instead of a DATETIME in my database, I used timestamp and time()... How would I check it then?