# Add one hour to PHP variable with date

Tags: php, date

The title says it all. I have a PHP variable that says: `07/05/2016`.

I've tried `strtodate`, the `date` function, but nothing seems to be working. **How can I now add one hour to this date?**

Comment: Strtodate and get a timestamp, then add 3600 seconds to it?

Comment: `07/05/2016`.... is that supposed to be 7th of May, or 5th of July?

Comment: Or this one: [Adding minutes to date time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a few ways to do this with PHP. Here's one using `DateTime()`:

```
$datetime = new DateTime('07/05/2016');
$datetime->modify('+1 hour');
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

In your case you can also just add the literal time since there is no time for that date and midnight is assumed:

```
echo '07/05/2016 01:00:00';
```

Just for fun, here are a few more ways to do it:

```
// Using DateInterval()
$datetime = new DateTime('07/05/2016');
$datetime->add(new DateInterval('PT1H'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

// As a one-liner
echo (new DateTime('07/05/2016'))->->modify('+1 hour')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in a simple way

```
$date = "2019-08-20 17:00:00";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("{$date} +1 hour"));
//result 2019-08-20 18:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `+1 hour` will add one hour.

```
$date = 07/05/2016

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime ($date,"+1 hour"));
```

And for time,

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime ($date,"+1 hour"));
```