# Adding minutes with PHP for each date / time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database table in which I want to store scheduled datetime records.
I'm trying to use PHP date function `$schedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

I want to add 1 minute to each record but keep the adding like `++`:

```
// needed result:
2018-02-08 10:00:00
2018-02-08 10:01:00
2018-02-08 10:02:00
```

My code looks slimier to this (tried to use stortime but it didn't worked):

```
$schedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//$schedule = strtotime('2018-02-18 19:00 + 1 minute'); 

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET schedule='$schedule'";
    $stm = $db->query($sql);
}
```

Looking for a solution to keep date and time format as described with simple increase by minutes...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding minutes to date time in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169139/adding-minutes-to-date-time-in-php)

Comment: In your loop, try `$schedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1 minute', strtotime($schedule)));`.

Comment: If you add more slime, it will look even slimier.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$current_time = time();
$next_time = strtotime('+1 minute', $current_time);
$schedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $next_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. First get the date/time of `$schedule` then add `1` to the `$schedule` date/time after update query, so after adding `1` minute to database it will again add `1` minute and so on.

```
$schedule = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET schedule='$schedule'";
    $stm = $db->query($sql);
    $schedule = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 minutes', $schedule));

}
```

Comment: `strtotime('+1 minutes', $schedule)` will fail : _"A non well formed numeric value encountered"_