# How to add times dynamically in php

Tags: php, html, datetime, foreach

I am getting the duration of a video like `9:55` or `00:13:51` . I want to add these values in a loop in `php`

I have tried like

```
    $t_duartion =0;
    foreach ($learn_detail->video_det as $video_det){
        $t_duartion += date("H:i:s",strtotime($video_det->duration));
    }
```

But the result is not coming. Its not coming as hh:mm:ss format. How to achieve this guys in `php`.

Any body idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Adding 15 minutes to Time value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557059/php-adding-15-minutes-to-time-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the durations together in seconds first and then use `date()`.

Example:

```
$t_duartion = 0; // Typo in variable name btw.

foreach ( $learn_detail->video_det as $video_det ) {
    // Add duration of current video in seconds to total count.
    $t_duartion += strtotime( $video_det->duration );
}

// Convert total seconds to hh:mm:ss format.
$time = date( 'H:i:s', $t_duartion );
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your logic your trying to add 00:13:00 and 09:14:53 etc which is wrong.try this:

```
    foreach ($learn_detail->video_det as $video_det){
        $t_duartion += strtotime($video_det->duration);
    }
$t_duartion = date("H:i:s",$t_duartion);
```