# Adding 30 minutes to time difference

Tags: php, codeigniter

The time is in this format - 09:00:00 - which is 09:30:00. I then 
     need 
     to add 30 minutes to this and store that in a separate variable 
     dynamically.

```
Example:
$selectedTime = "9:00:00";
$endTime = strtotime("+30 minutes", strtotime($selectedTime));
echo date('h:i:s', $endTime);


output:
 9:00:00  to 9:30:00
 9:31:00  to 10:00:00
 10:01:00  to 10:30:00, etc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Adding 15 minutes to Time value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557059/php-adding-15-minutes-to-time-value/20557225)

Answer (score 0):

Use **date** function for this purpuse.

```
$selectedTime = "9:00:00";
$endTime = date('H:i:s',strtotime('+30 minutes',strtotime($selectedTime)));
echo $endTime;
```

> Output : 09:30:00

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**
*use `strtotime` to get the desired result like this :*

Working demo : https://eval.in/1020357

```
$previous_time = "9:00:00";
$endTime = strtotime("+30 minutes", strtotime($previous_time));

echo  $previous_time. ' To '.date('H:i:s', $endTime) ;
```

Output :

```
9:00:00 To 09:30:00
```

For more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php