# How to add period to only TIME (02:00:00) in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime

I want to add a specific period like 2 hours to only time. 
BUT only TIME. There will be no date related issue.

Like my time is 02:00:00 
And I want to add 1 hour to this time. 
So, the result will be 03:00:00

Is there any PHP built-in function like strtotime()? 
I don't want explode related function for this like explode(":", $time)

Is it possible? Please help someone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557059/php-adding-15-minutes-to-time-value#20557225 Protip: 1 hour is 60 minutes. With all due respect, but questions like yours have been answered correctly and upvoted to 100 at least 500 times by now. Next time do a little more research.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$new_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("+ 1 hours"))`

or if you would just like the timestamp:

`strtotime("+ 1 hours")`