# how can I create a list of times in php?

Tags: php

I have x.

x is minutes.

I have a string start_time like: 7:00

And I have a string end_time like: 14:00

how can print a list of time with increase x  minutes for each loop?

I want print something like this:

```
if x = 30

7:00 - 7:30
7:30 - 8:00
...
13:30 - 14:00
```

I try do it with math functions in php like this:

```
$time = '7:00';
$mm = $hh = 0;
$str = explode(":",$time);
if(($str[1]+ $x) > 60)
{
...
}
```

but it there a more simple method? can date function in php do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767068/adding-30-minutes-to-time-formatted-as-hi-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) together with [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to achieve this.

Create two `DateTime` intervals with your start and end times, and a `DateInterval` instance with the number of minutes you need. Then, create a `DatePeriod` with this information, and iterate over it to show the resulting times:

```
<?php
$minutes = 15;
$start = "07:00";
$end = "14:00";
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $start);
$endDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $end);
$interval = new DateInterval("PT".$minutes."M");
$dateRange = new DatePeriod($startDate, $interval, $endDate);
foreach ($dateRange as $date) {
    echo $date->format("H:i")."<br>";
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/K9n6E)

*Result*

> 07:00
>
> 07:15
>
> 07:30
>
> 07:45
>
> 08:00
>
> 08:15
>
> 08:30
>
> 08:45
>
> 09:00
>
> 09:15
>
> 09:30
>
> 09:45
>
> 10:00
>
> 10:15
>   // etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object along with a desired [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object.

Example: https://3v4l.org/lg8QW

```
$start = new \DateTime('07:00');
$end = new \DateTime('14:00');
$interval = new \DateInterval('PT1M'); //change to desired interval
$periods = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($periods as $period) {
   echo $period->format('H:i') ;
}
```

Result:

```
07:00
07:01
07:02
07:03
07:04
07:05
07:06
07:07
07:08
07:09
07:10
07:11
07:12
07:13
07:14
07:15
07:16
07:17
07:18
07:19
07:20
//...
13:59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime` object.
just like this:

```
<?php

$start_time = '7:00';

$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $start_time);
$old = $start_time;

while (true) {
    $date1->modify('+30 min');
    echo $old . '-' . $date1->format('H:i').PHP_EOL;

    $old = $date1->format('H:i');
    if ($old == '14:00')  {
        break;
    }
}
```

Output:

> 7:00-07:30
>   07:30-08:00
>   08:00-08:30
>   ...
>   13:30-14:00

More info just see the manual here: [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)